# Manipulating hexadecimal numbers in Pascal

Tags: integer, hex, pascal, number-manipulation

I'm currently reading up on binary and hexadecimal number manipulation and I'm finding it difficult to complete a task and was wondering if anyone can help clarify this question for me.

I have a hexadecimal number '04831037' and I need to replace the first number (0) with a '1' via a Pascal program. I'm not sure how to go about doing this.

I know how to convert an integer into a hexadecimal value via:

```
var 
  iNumber : Integer;

begin
  iNumber := 75698231;
  writeln(IntToHex(iNumber, 8));
end.

> Output: 04831037
```

But now I am confused on how to replace a single number in the output. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hexadecimal numbers are of base 16, i.e. each digit represents a value 0..15.

To form a value of ex. 16, i.e. $10 following expression could be used:
(*Note: the $ sign means that the value is a hexadecimal value*)

> 16 = $10 = 1*16<sup>1</sup> + 0*16<sup>0</sup>

The value 28 ($1C) is expressed by:

> 28 = $1C = 1*16<sup>1</sup> + 12*16<sup>0</sup>

To add $10000000 to a number, use

> $10000000 = 1*16<sup>7</sup>

In code that would look like:

```
iNumber := iNumber + $10000000;
```

---

Lets look at the question:

> *I have a hexadecimal number '04831037' and I need to replace the first number (0) with a '1'*

This means you will first subtract the number with $00000000 and then add $10000000.

In code that would be:

```
iNumber := $04831037;
iNumber := iNumber - $00000000 + $10000000;
WriteLn(IntToHex(iNumber,8)); // Writes '14831037'
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, it was a great help. I just wanted to know If I have a int64 number that gets stored in a variable along with another int64 number in another variable. How would I add the second variable number to the end of the first one?

Comment: Not sure I understand, but adding a number to another variable is `int64_1 := int64_1 + int64_2`

Comment: Sorry for the poor explanation. So int64_1 is given a 14 digit value and int64_2 is given a 1 digit value. If I viewed the int64_1 value like so IntToHex(int61_1, 16) the number would look something like: 0000520012301936. I would like to replace the first 0 in int64_1 and add the value of int64_2 in its place.

Comment: `int64_1 := int64_1 - $0000000000000000 + int64_2;` I can't see how this would be any different than what is expressed in my answer. Note that subtracting with zero is just to show the principle. It could have been that you wanted to replace a 9 with a 3.

Comment: You're right this is no different to original your answer. My explanation is still poor. The value of `int64_1` is assigned `$0000520012301935` and `int64_2` is assigned `$0000000000000001` so `int64_1 := int64_1 - $0000000000000000 + int64_2` would now make `int64_1 = $000052001230193**6**`. if I wanted to replace the first 0 in `int64_1` I would first have to do something like: `in64_2 := int64_2 * (16^15)` then repeat the earlier code. Is there a better method. I'm sorry, I need to do further research and study into this.

Comment: Why assign `$0000000000000001` to `int64_2`, when you could assign `$1000000000000000` ? Also keep in mind that you should use `uInt64` when working with such high positive numbers. In pascal you have the `Power(base,exp)` function. In some compilers also the `IntPower(base,exp)` function. Use the `Round()` function to convert the floating point result to integer. Some pascal compilers also have bit-handling operators, like `SHL` and `SHR`, which could be used to convert `$1` to `$1000000000000000` by shifting left.